# Получить max значение в битрикс

Tags: sql, битрикс

Добрый день.

Только вчера начал работать с 1с-битрикс, и нужно получить max значение id из бд. Простой запрос не работает, до orm еще руки не дошли, а нужно уже вчера. Помогите с кодом, кто знает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я так понял, max id у элемента, в битриксе есть определенное правило наименования таблиц в зависимости от классов, поэтому для класса `CIBlockElement` соответсвует таблица `b_iblock_element`, и там sql получи последнюю запись и его id